# Adjust RichTextBox font size under High DPI setting

Tags: c#, richtextbox, scaling, dpi

My C# application includes grids with both simple text boxes and richtext boxes.  Often the richtext boxes contain rich text copied and pasted from elsewhere, and often the rtf markup includes hardcoded font size (\fsXX, XX in half points).  In most cases the rich text font size is the same or close to the simple text font size.

When the DPI scaling is set to anything other than the default 96 the rich text is distorted as follows:

a) When the application is NOT set to be DPI aware the richtext is shown smaller than the simple text and is blurry.

b) When the application is set to be DPI aware the rich text is larger than the simple text.

Is there a means to allow or force the richtext to scale with the simple text, short of editing the markup directly?

Comment: Did you try richtextbox v5?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? It might make it easier to help you...

Comment: How are the fonts defined for the simple text boxes are they in point sizes or pixels?

Comment: One more thing, the world of high dpi on windows is slightly more complicated than you are seeing so far. As well as getting the app to work at 96 dpi, you also want to test at dpi's between 96 and 149 then >150. The dpi aware flag which causes stretching when set to false doesn't start working until the dpi is at least 150.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might solve the problem is to set the RichTextBox on a form and set the `AutoScaleMode` property of the form to `None` ([AutoScaleMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set its property **WordWrap** to **true**.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use a WPF form, so you don't have to worry about de DPI of different screens

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,
        template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js"
    });
</script>


<td class="textboxmain" style="height:300px; "><asp:TextBox id="textbox1" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100%" runat="server" placeholder="test............"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

Comment: download tinymce 3 party tools also

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following, it is supported only in .NET Framework 4.5.2 onwards. Microsoft has covered a few more controls for HighDpiAutoresizing.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: this feature was introduced in 4.5.1 and still doesn't support scaling Richtextbox up to version 4.6.1. More infos here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx